# EF Core 6: Find name of Intermediate table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

Since EF Core 5, it's incredibly easy to generate many-to-many tables without having to explicitly define the intermediate table. However, I'd like to be able to get the name of the autogenerated intermediate table between two entities. For example, let's say I have two entities:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

And I create a DbContext containing these two entities, create a migration and then apply it to my database, I'd expect to three tables generated:

- `Foos`
- `Bars`
- `FooBars`

Is there a way, given either `Foo` or `Bar` (or `Foo.Bars` or `Bars.Foos`), to find the name of the automatically generated table name of `FooBars`?

Comment: Have you tried to examine IModel? `context.Model`

Comment: Yes, I've been exploring IModel this afternoon, but haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the name like so:

```
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Foo>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Bars)
    .WithMany(p => p.Foos)
    .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("FooBars"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you always have the option to name your intermediate table that holds the many to many relationship.

So, if you let EF Core handle the intermediate table, you can't specify a name, but you can call `UsingEntity<T>` while defining it to specify a table name.

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=FoobarmanytomanySample;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true")
                      .UseLazyLoadingProxies();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entry>()
                    .HasMany(x => x.Foos)
                    .WithMany(x => x.Bars)
                    .UsingEntity<Dictionary<string, object>>(
                        "FooBars",
                        x => x.HasOne<Tag>().WithMany(),
                        x => x.HasOne<Entry>().WithMany());
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this, but I appreciate the suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found a way of doing it. There's no exception handling and I'm not sure how brittle it is, but it's working for my DbContext. An example:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public string GetIntermediateTableNameForEntityProperty(Type entity, string propertyName)
    {
        IEntityType entityType = base.Model.FindEntityType(entity);
        ISkipNavigation propSkipNavigation = entityType.GetSkipNavigations().Single(x => string.Equals(x.Name, propertyName));
        IForeignKey foreignKey = propSkipNavigation.ForeignKey;
        IProperty foreignKeyProperty = foreignKey.Properties.Single();
        string intermediateTableName = foreignKeyProperty.DeclaringEntityType.Name;
        return intermediateTableName;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
public class Baz
{
    private readonly AppDbContext _appDbContext;

    public Baz(AppDbContext appDbContext)
    {
        _appDbContext = appDbContext;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var intermediateTableName = _appDbContext.GetIntermediateTableNameForEntityProperty(typeof(Foo), nameof(Foo.Bars));
        // intermediateTableName = "FooBars"
    }
}
```